# How to run a JS funktion before Metro replaces my React Native JS code via "Reload"

Tags: react-native

I am writing a React Native app with hardware access. This means that I setup the hardware at application startup. Then I could click "Reload" in the developer menu. But before the code is reloaded I need to tear down my hardware setup since otherwise the setup during restart fails.

Is there any way I can create some kind of callback function/hook that allows me to get informed immediately before app reload? Than I could to the tear down in this function. Please note the code has to run in the handy app (not as a kind of plugin for metro bundler).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see hardware configuration permission notifications every time?

Comment: No. Its not about the hardware configuration permission. In fact the hardware access is not very relevant for this question. The question is more general about a mechanism for getting a chance t tear down *anything* before restarting the app and setting it up again.